# Lavalamp Menu Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, themes, tumblr

I'm working on a tumblr theme for my blog. I want to implement lavalamp into my menu, but I've tried so many different things & can't seem to get it to work. I'm not an expert at jquery, so I'd really appreciate some help!!!

My blog is http://jamescharless.tumblr.com If you want to see it live.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ww0u3rz/pREn35wbh/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ww0u3rz/I0Xn35wl8/jquery.lavalamp.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/ww0u3rz/H7un35wai/jquery-1.1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#lava").lavaLamp({
            fx: "backout", 
            speed: 700,
            click: function(event, menuItem) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

And the CSS:

```
    ul.navigation {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.navigation li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

ul.navigation li.back {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #e6e8ea;
    width: 9px;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
}

ul.navigation li a {
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    color: #999;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    top: 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto 10px;
}

ul.navigation li a:hover, 
ul.navigation li a:active, 
ul.navigation li a:visited {
    border: none;
}
```

And finally, the HTML:

```
<ul class="navigation" id="lava">
                    <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/msg">message</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">archives</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">faq</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: In your code you have  <nav id="navigation"> and then <li> which are child elements of a ul, but your jquery function is trying to target an elememt with the id of lava id="lava", which does not exist in your code. I will post an answer below, which might work.

Answer (score -1):

Edit

Actually try this

jQuery:

```
 $(".navigation").lavaLamp({
// etc
```

HTML

```
  <nav id="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/msg">message</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">archives</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">faq</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

This may require an update to your css too.

Comment: Why don't you post all your code somewhere like here: pastebin.com

Comment: Hey, could it be that you are calling jquery library after the other jquery plugins? Try moving http://static.tumblr.com/ww0u3rz/H7un35wai/jquery-1.1.3.1.min.js above the other two script tags.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what the result should look like?

http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/Aee9W/

I am calling jquery first, then the other plugins as they are dependent on jquery.

```
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/ww0u3rz/H7un35wai/jquery-1.1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ww0u3rz/pREn35wbh/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ww0u3rz/I0Xn35wl8/jquery.lavalamp.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, this works so not sure why the silly downvoting.